# load content by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have created this ajax script for loading data.

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()  
    var loading = "<img src='/images/loading.gif' alt='Loading...' />";
    var scrolltop=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollTop');
    var scrollheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollHeight');
    var windowheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('clientHeight');
//  var post = $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).val();
    var form_data = $('#search_form').serialize();// + "&" + post ;

    var scrolloffset=20;
    $('#search').html(loading);
    $.post("dosearch.php",form_data,function(newitems) {
        $('#content').append(newitems);
            });
        if(scrolltop>=(scrollheight-(windowheight+scrolloffset))){
            $.post("dosearch.php",form_data,function(newitems) {
        $('#content').append(newitems);
            });
        }     
        });
});
```

this script will take form data and serialize them and post them to `dosearch.php` after that dosearch will post data which we search for **Limited** by 0,6. when scroller reach to bottom of result's div i want to fetch more content and for that reason i created this function which will take our form data again and number of div in my result div...ill then use this div result just in case to limit $number,6.

```
function scroll_result(form_data){
    var loading = "<img src='/images/loading.gif' alt='Loading...' />";
    var scrolltop=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollTop');
    var scrollheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollHeight');
    var windowheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('clientHeight');
    var scrolloffset=20;
    var divnumber = $('#content').children().size();
    var form_data = form_data + "&size=" + divnumber;

    if(scrolltop>=(scrollheight-(windowheight+scrolloffset)))
    {
        //fetch new items
        $.post('dosearch.php', form_data, function(newitems){
        $('#content').append(newitems);
        });
    }
    setTimeout('scroll_result(form_data)', 1500);
}
```

this function dont work and i need some help on this

thanks in advance...

Comment: Where is your scroll listener ?

Comment: myscroll listener is this div #scrollbox when i reach to bottom of this div if(scrolltop>=(scrollheight-(windowheight+scrolloffset))){ this will execute and something must happen which i dont know what must happen :) maybe some repeat function to repeat this process?

Comment: are you getting any errors ? as you reach the bottom of the div does the new ajax call fire again ? what does the scrollresult function do ?

Comment: no errors but no functionality either.i just improved my code how can i post it?post it as comment or answer?

Comment: scroll result doesnt do anything ..i just design scrol result to fire up this ajax when i reach to bottom of this div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just setup a sample scroll listening application here :

http://jsfiddle.net/E2wj2/2/

You need to listen to scroll event for your `scrollbox` ,

```
$('#scrollbox').scroll(function(){
  console.log('scrolling');
  scrolltop=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollTop');
  if(scrolltop>=(scrollheight-(windowheight+scrolloffset))) {
    //do whatever you wish to do
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if i listen to this event ill get more data if scroller reach to bottom of this div?

Comment: Yes. Essentially what you are doing is listening to the scroll event, and checking if you have reached the bottom of the div. If true, fire your new `ajax` request.

Comment: i realy love this sort of answer which will teach new things..i didnt knew about scroll listener at all.and that was the problem.realy thanks..answer accepted